# Getting Error while using mongoose populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting below error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

I am multiple models and mostly all are connected to each other so i have put all in single file and included that file. I have use below method to export.

```
module.exports = {
    User: User,
    Category: Category,
    Property: Property    
}
```

My include code is as below:

```
var models      = require('../../app/models/revstance_models');
var Property    = models.Property;
var Category    = models.Category;
var User        = models.User;
```

My code to retrive data is as below :

```
exports.showMyListingPage = async function(req, res) {
    let properties = await Property.find({}).populate({path: 'user',
  model: 'User',}).exec();
    console.log(properties[0].user);
}
```

My get getting below error message as a result :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema) at new MissingSchemaError (/home/pct26/Rushabh/Project/RevstancePhaseII/RST/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/missingSchema.js:20:11)
at NativeConnection.Connection.model (/home/pct26/Rushabh/Project/RevstancePhaseII/RST/myapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:791:11)
```

Here is my model definitions :

https://pastebin.com/nE4mDx9N

Comment: I have attached pastebin link that will show my models summary

Comment: Replace `var User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);` with  `var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)`

Comment: it will change users table User, i am right ? checking your suggestion

Comment: Now it returns user: null

Comment: Try to remove `model: User` as we already referenced it in our property schema... If doesn't work show your both the collections... It would be better if you will ask a new question related to your new doubt

Comment: As it create User table and it has no data, so i have create new user and add it's object id to property table and it returns user data.